# iOS - Move TableView before scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, tableview

I have a view with an image and a tableview. The image is in the first half of the screen (portrait) and the tableview in the second half. And now I want to move the tableview over the image until it reaches the top and covers the image. Then it should start the "real scrolling".

But what's the best way to do this? Can I like replace the touchesMove of the variable tableView? I could create an extension of the UITableView and override the function, but then I don't have access to the view of my Controller to move the tableView.

Any answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The imageView should be behind the tableView with constraints top, leading, trailing to superview and height to superview with a multiplier of 0.5.  The tableView should fill its superview.

The trick is that you add a tableViewHeader that is invisible and equal to half the height of the screen.  This has the effect of pushing the initial content of the tableView off the screen.  In interface builder add a UIView to the tableView as header and make it transparent.  Also make the background of your tableView transparent.  Take an outlet to the headerView and the tableView.  In viewDidLayoutSubviews set your headerView.frame.size.height = tableView.frame.size.height / 2.

Comment: thank you! But how can I get just the header transparent? I have created a new View, set the alpha to 0.0 and background to UIColor.clear. The bounds are are x:0, y:0, width: screen width, height: screen height /2 . Then I set it with tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView . Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Josh answered, what you can try is:

What you can do is make the `UIImageView`'s height decrease based on the scroll amount until the `UIImageView`'s height is 0 and then start the scrolling otherwise force the `contentOffSet` of the `UITableView` to always remain 0. That being said, here is how to do it:

Make an enum to keep track of the various states of the `UIImageView` like:

```
enum Layout {

     case ImageExpanding,
     case ImageDefaultHeight,
     case ImageDiminishing,
     case ImageNotVisible
}
```

In your storyboard, add a top, leading and trailing constraint to the superview for your `UIImageView` and fixed height constraint of lets say 200(don't worry you will change this later). To your `UITableView` add a leading, trailing and bottom constraint to the superview and a top the `UIImageView`. Now drag and drop a constraint outlet for the `UIImageView` height into your `UIViewController`.

In your `viewDidLoad` set your `heightConstraint` to be 1/2 of the total screen height and set the enum state to initially be `ImageDefaultHeight`

Now in your `scrollViewDidScroll` you will have to check the direction of the scroll and based on that while checking the current state of the image, increase or decrease the heightConstraint based on the amount a user scrolls by and always check:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

     if(/*up*/){
          //just telling you about this if condition as this will ensure that 
          //if your table view is large and if tableview isn't at the top, 
          //the image shouldn't expand

           if layout == .ImageNotVisible{

               if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {

                    //start expanding once you reach top of tableview
                    layout = .ImageExpanding;
               }
           }

          //keep track of other enum states and update your uiimageview 
          //appropriately after calculating the user scroll amount         
          //until the height reaches your initialDefaultHeight and 
          //then do nothing. You will have to figure out the code 
          //for this on your own


     }else if(/*down*/){

          //make image smaller
     }

     //dont let table view scroll until image height is 0 when use is scrolling down
     if layout != ImageNotVisible{

         scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
     }
}
```